# Spring Resttemplate postforobject returns null as object response if used with ClientHttpRequestInterceptor

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to consume a rest service and i am posting some data, with Spring `RestTemplate` `postForObjectMethod` but i am getting a null response, even though i can see the request and response in payload.

[Update] I am using an interceptor implmenting `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, if i remove it, i am getting the response.

[PS: the service is configured as POST, ideally it should be GET for obvious reason, but i am still curious why no response is coming as part of post, even i can see the same in http logs.]

Configuration Spring MVC 4 based application

Application context:

```
 <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.sipl.interceptors.LoggingRequestInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Jackson POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Interceptor Class

```
public class LoggingRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingRequestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        traceRequest(request, body);
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        traceResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void traceRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("===========================request begin================================================");

        logger.debug("URI : " + request.getURI());
        logger.debug("Method : " + request.getMethod());
        logger.debug("Request Body : " + new String(body, "UTF-8"));
        logger.debug("==========================request end================================================");
    }

    private void traceResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            inputStringBuilder.append(line);
            inputStringBuilder.append('\n');
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        logger.debug("============================response begin==========================================");
        logger.debug("status code: " + response.getStatusCode());
        logger.debug("status text: " + response.getStatusText());
        logger.debug("Response Body : " + inputStringBuilder.toString());
        logger.debug("=======================response end=================================================");
    }

}
```

GetAllEmployeesClass

```
public class GetAllEmployeesVO {
    private ResponseVO response;
    private List<EmployeeBean> employees;
    private String actionCode;

    public String getActionCode() {
        return actionCode;
    }

    public void setActionCode(String actionCode) {
        this.actionCode = actionCode;
    }

    public ResponseVO getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(ResponseVO response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public List<EmployeeBean> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<EmployeeBean> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class RestAdminstrationController {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Value("${rest.getallemployees.api.endpoint}")
    private String getEmpEndpt;

    @RequestMapping(value = AppConstatants.GET_EXISTING_APP_USERS, method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public List<EmployeeBean> loadAppAdminUsers(@RequestBody GetAllEmployeesVO userData) {

        try {
            //get Rest Service Data
            GetAllEmployeesVO resp= restTemplate.postForObject(getEmpEndpt,userData,GetAllEmployeesVO.class);
            //resp is coming as null
```

Request Response HTTP payload logs:

```
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG RestTemplate:79 - Created POST request for "http://103.35.123.23:8080/siplrestservices/sipl/EmployeeService/getAllEmployees"
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG RestTemplate:720 - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG RestTemplate:797 - Writing [com.sipl.common.beans.GetAllEmployeesVO@1dd42575] using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@52e7339f]
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:36 - ===========================request begin================================================
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:38 - URI : http://xxxxx:8080/siplrestservices/sipl/EmployeeService/getAllEmployees
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:39 - Method : POST
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:40 - Request Body : {"response":null,"employees":null,"actionCode":"M"}
2015-12-12 15:45:53 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:41 - ==========================request end================================================
2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:53 - ============================response begin==========================================
2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:54 - status code: 201
2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:55 - status text: Created
2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:56 - **Response Body : {"employees":[{"commonName":"MOHAN KUMAR GHOSHAL","countryCode":"","dateOfJoining":"2015-11-23","designationId":"4","division":"GENERAL","emailId":"","employeeId":"1","employeeNo":"M-392","employeeStatus":"1","hqCityId":"2","lastWorkingDate":"2015-11-23","mobile":{"mobileStatus":"1"},"mobileNo":"1234567890"}],"response":{"respCd":"0","respDesc":"SUCCESS"}}**

2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG LoggingRequestInterceptor:57 - =======================response end=================================================
2015-12-12 15:45:54 DEBUG RestTemplate:632 - POST request for "http://xxxxx:8080/siplrestservices/sipl/EmployeeService/getAllEmployees" resulted in 201 (Created)
```

Comment: You can only read the response once, you are already reading and processing it in the interceptor so there is nothing to process anymore. You would have to wrap the input stream, tap it/copy it so that it can be read again. You would at least have to `reset` the input stream and depending on your used implementation that might work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.
It allows multiple reading of the response.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Nati I did the following changes to my rest template and it worked like charm.

```
<bean id="SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
<bean id="BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.sipl.interceptors.LoggingRequestInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```